# Run java-exported tests generated from selenium ide on selenium server standalone

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Is i possible to run java exported tests from selenium ide on selenium-server.jar trough command line/terminal?

So far I have used this command:

```
java -jar lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -htmlsuite *firefox http://localhost:4444/wd/hub src/NewTest.java NewTest-result.html
```

It works ok until the firefox is lanuched and I see the code of this test in firefox but it doesn't show that it has run the test at all. It says 0 test run, 0 tests failed, 0 tests successful.

Is it my command wrong or selenium server is not supposed to be used this way?

I even tried to use the html version of NewTest instead of java but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converted tests are JUnit tests. So you should have two processes:

**Your selenium server process:**

```
java -jar lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
```

**Your [JUnit test runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-testcases-from-command-line)**

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [test class name]
```

If you have several test classes, it might be better to create a `TestSuite` with the [Suite](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-5-suite-test/) annotation:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
   MyTestClass1.class,
   MyTestClass2.class})
public class TestSuite {
   ...
```

If you are using [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/testing.html), you can setup config containing selenium server address, browser, ...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:my/package/seleniumConfig.xml"})
public abstract class SeleniumTestSuite {
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [I want to run Selenium test case file from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231975/i-want-to-run-selenium-test-case-file-from-command-line)

Make sure your command line matches -

`java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*<browser>" "http://<ip>" "<suite to run>.html" "<path to results>.html"`