# Easy to use multi browser automation tool for record, parameterize, debug, batch run of suites and results report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, browser-automation, regression-testing

I'm new in tests area. Regression team where I belong has built GUI tests for some web applications with complex business logic that developers team has produced.

Until now, we have been using Selenium IDE to build regression tests (record, edit, parameterize, debug and playback). Tests are exported and maintained in Html format. We used to have a tool to manage tests and iterations (store html scripts/tests suites, run tests in batch mode, run tests in background, get detailed test result reports), which is now deprecated because uses Selenium RC. Additionally, tests are made only in Firefox, but our clients are mainly IE users.

So, we have some important and strategic decisions to make. We need urgently to start testing in IE and a new way to do the tasks we were doing.

An attempt was made to change the code of tests’ manager tool in order to work with Selenium Webdriver. It was tried to code tests in Ruby from the beginning, since Selenium IDE export to Ruby was not satisfactory. We figured out that huge changes and subsequent tests on the manager tool were needed. It would also involve programming the methods and test them.

Our regression team is quite small and we don’t want to focus too much on the programming task itself, but more on testing our webApps. Additionally, no one on the general team had experience in working with Ruby before.

Can you help us with some suggestions about the route we should take?

Is there an integrated solution easy to work with (as Selenium IDE) and able to do the manager tasks of our old tool without taking us much time on “hard coding”?

Is there any reliable open source tool that could do it? And a commercial solution?

Comment: SO is a very poor medium for this kind of discussion. Your best option is to hire a decent contractor to come in and build you a solution that satisfies your needs.

Comment: Wrong place to post your question.. But as a suggestion, provide your mail to contact if someone is interested to solve your problem.

Comment: You can run the HTML tests from the command line against IE.

Comment: @Dmart, how can I run the HTML tests from the command line against IE? Can you give me a clue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231975/i-want-to-run-selenium-test-case-file-from-command-line
Change *firefox to *iexplore