# How to click a button when a page loads

Tags: javascript, bash

Ive got to programmatically click a cookie accept button when a page loads. I tried a few different addons that are showed online. Those did not work...

The button has the following code:

```
<a id="acceptAllPrivacyOptionsAtag" class="bcGiveConsent bcpConsentButtonAtag bcpConsentOKButtonAtag" aria-label="accept all privacy options" role="button"> accept all cookies  </a>
```

Is there a way to do this in javascript? I have to execute the code in bash shell when the page loads.

Comment: You can easily do it in JavaScript of course, using getElementById('acceptAllPrivacyOptionsAtag').click(). However, how will you run that from bash? Well, you can't. So, as simple as it sounds like it should be, you probably need something like Selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231975/i-want-to-run-selenium-test-case-file-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a thing called Alert() it would be alright when page loads, not the best option tho.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t) answer.

Add a script tag at the bottom portion of your html code and trigger a click event manually.

`document.getElementById('acceptAllPrivacyOptionsAtag').click()`