# How can I make Selenium IDE start and run by clicking on a test case

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How can I make Selenium IDE start and run by clicking on a test case?

We want to upload all the test cases on our server as links on an HTML page and when a link is clicked, SElenium IDE would open and run the script.

IS this possible?

Comment: As per i know it is not possible.As Selenium IDE is a Firefox plugin which will not be open after click on any link.Why not you try using RC help [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144744/how-do-i-launch-the-selenium-ide-from-the-command-line-with-a-specific-test-case

Comment: well the idea was for everyone in the company to be able to just click and run tests, and this way I have to teach them how to do it. If I install Web Driver, can it run test cases written in Selenium IDE HTML?

Comment: you can run the selenium ide script in HTML format from selenium RC using Testrunner.use next help [link](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SIDE/Automating+Selenium+IDE+tests)