# How to make selenium run in terminal

Tags: selenium

I need selenium to run in my terminal and integrate selenium testing into a build scaffolding, ant. so we run the tests like...

> ant selenium-test localhost

First I installed the selenium IDE plugin but I am not if it is possible to make this run from terminal. My question is that Can I do it with Selenium RC? Can anyone give me any hint of how to make it run from command line?

Thanks

Comment: not sure..i have tried with TestNG-Selenium-Maven

Comment: Can you explain more or give me any reference? thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you even try searching first?
[How do I launch the Selenium IDE from the command line with a specific test case loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144744/how-do-i-launch-the-selenium-ide-from-the-command-line-with-a-specific-test-case)

It is also worth mentioning that Selenium IDE tests are normally very brittle, and running them from any CI system will likely produce very large parentage of false negatives. This will further lead to general frustration with automation for the entire development team.

Lastly, Selenium RC is now considered deprecated (retired?) technology. If you are starting a new project, it is recommended that you chose Selenium WebDriver.