# Start selenium ide from command line with base url

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, firefox, command-line, selenium-ide

1. It is possible to start selenium ide from cmd with hardcoded base url?
   For example `google.com`?
2. It is possible to set default path where test will be saved - with cmd? And with default format - i.e `Java / JUnit 4 / WEbDriver`?

For now i can start ide and firefox with such command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe\" -chrome "chrome://selenium-ide/content/"
```

I dont want to use Selenium RC or start testcases from command line. i need to be able to start IDE with those options i mentioned above - and if it is possible to stop recording test case in ide also using cmd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to run Selenium test case file from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231975/i-want-to-run-selenium-test-case-file-from-command-line)

Comment: @user3872094 As i explained above, i dont want to use RC, and there is no answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144744/how-do-i-launch-the-selenium-ide-from-the-command-line-with-a-specific-test-case), do this:

```
c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -chrome "chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/TestRunner.html?baseUrl=http://localhost&test=file:///c:\tests\testsuite.html&auto=true"
```

or on MacOS;

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin --chrome "chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/TestRunner.html?baseUrl=http://localhost&test=file:////Users/user/Documents/test.html&auto=true"
```